# Java: comments /* * * */

Tags: java, comments

Quick question, it there a difference between:

```
/* This is first line of comments
This is the second line
And this will be the last line
*/
```

and:

```
 /*This is first line of comments
*This is the second line
*And this will be the last line 
*/
```

in java language?

**The source I learned  from teaches the second form, but I found out the fist one works too.**

Comment: No. Both are comments

Comment: Well, the second one has extra asterisks in it. What difference do you speculate there might be?

Comment: Difference with respect to what? Nothing in a comment has an impact on the semantics of the code. However, it be interpreted differently by a tool interpreting the comments (e.g. a documentation tool).

Comment: Do you know what [tag:javadoc] is?

Comment: I'm sorry, the site I learned this in used the second format, so I thought there might be a difference.

Comment: -6? This question ain't so bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference at all as far as the compiler is concerned. It's just a matter of what looks pretty and what documentation generators rely upon. **That last point is surprisingly important: particularly in Java.** (Javadoc relies upon well-defined comment forms.) `/*` defines the start of a comment, and you'll stay in "comment mode" until the first `*/` is reached.

So further `/*` are allowed within a comment block (but they don't nest so you still only need one closing `*/`). And the single line comment `//` within a comment block is benign: `//*/` will close a comment block.

Answer (score 2):

There is difference between

```
/* This is first line of comments
This is the second line
And this will be the last line
*/
```

And

```
/**
 * This is javadoc
 * Refer to <a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/">javadoc</a> for details
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

> /* text.... */

```
The compiler ignores everything from /* to */.
```

> /** documentation */

```
This is a documentation comment and in general its called doc comment.
The JDK javadoc tool uses doc comments when preparing automatically generated documentation.
```